# ReactJS - Disabling a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component, disabled-input

I need to disable `PostList` component in its initial state.

```
import React from 'react';
import PostList from './PostList';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className="ui container">
             <PostList />
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Whats the best way to disable (and grey out) a component? Possible solutions are to pass a value as props and then apply it to a ui element, However please keep in mind that `PostList` may have inner nested components as well. Please share an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you mentioned in a comment that instead of hiding it, you want to grey it instead. I would use the disabled state and style the component. Since `PostList` could be nested, we don't know what the props are since you did not specify them.

Also, I assuming that you are not using `styled-components`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import PostList from "./PostList";

const App = () => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="ui container">
      <PostList
        style={{
          opacity: disabled ? 0.25 : 1,
          pointerEvents: disabled ? "none" : "initial"
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: What do you mean by styled-components? Sorry learning reactjs and still a rookie reactjs dev.

Comment: @Ahmed This library [here](https://www.styled-components.com). It is quite a popular library used in React to style components.

Comment: oh no no :D I havent used it at all. Infact hearing about it the first time.

Comment: Ill check that out. My current challenge here is that I am not sure what useState does. So ill read up on that.

Comment: `useState` is a new addition called `hooks` introduced in React v16.8

Comment: How will I enable it after a certain action? will I have to do something conditional above like in const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);?

Comment: Something like `<button onClick={() => setDisabled(false)}` to change the state of the `disabled` value. You need to have knowledge on React Hooks for this

Comment: which basically means I can also save this in state or a reducer? and possibly create an action around it so that upon an action of a deeply nested component I am able to change the behavior? Would it be a bad practice to do such a thing for me?

Comment: No you don't have to use a reducer for this example

Comment: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Comment: Read up the Hooks documentation

Comment: use state didnt work for me however I was able to achieve the same with a different solution. Also style needs to be applied on div not the component otherwise it doesnt take any affect.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different ways I like to do something like this.

One way you can do it is by using state

```
this.state = {
  showList: false
}
```

and than something like

```
return (
   {this.state.showList && <PostList />}
)
```

Another option is to pass the showList in state as a prop, so something like

```
return(
<PostList show = {this.state.showList} />

)
```

and than in PostList something like

```
return props.show && (your component here)
```

You can also use conditional classNames, so if you want that component shown, you can throw a className and style it how you normally would, but if not, just throw a display: none. I usually save doing that for replacing a navbar with a dropdown button on smaller screens, but it is another option

Comment: Sorry I am very new to JS world. When you write the following line: return (
   {this.state.showList && <PostList />}
) How does this exactly work?

Comment: If `this.state.showList` is `true`, it will render the `<PostList />` component, otherwise it will just remove it from the DOM.

Comment: So the expression this.state.showList && (your component) is just a Boolean.

You can play around with this a little bit, but if you console.log(true && "Hello world"), Hello world will print. 

If the first expression evaluates to a Boolean, the second operation will run. If it is false, it will not. SO basically what is happening is (true && (component)), since this.state.showList is true, the component will render.

Comment: nice! Thank you for stating that. The only thing is that I dont want to hide a component per say. I want to disable it so that a user cannot get the feedback from ui components as well as they can understand the behavior of the component by looking at its disabled state.

Comment: Not a problem! I've made a few edits to my original answer because I made a few boo boos. When you said disabled, I thought you meant hide it. You are tying to make it so you can still see the component, but not interact with it? Im not sure how exactly your component works, but that's another thing you can use conditional classNames for, which is a similar approach. Something like

``` <div onClick = {this.props.show && 'Some function'} ```

This will disable an onclick event from firing when it shouldn't. Have you looked into ternary operators yet? They are great, especially in React